# How to pass parameter to Shell.sh_one in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

When I pass bytes variable to the method `Shell.sh_one` from `Core_extended` there is a strange error:

```
Error: This expression has type bytes but an expression was expected of 
type
     ('a, unit, bytes, bytes option) Core.Std.format4 =
       ('a, unit, bytes, bytes, bytes, bytes option) format6
```

What's interesting if I'll pass bytes literal, there is no error. Could someone explain this behaviour of Ocaml? Below there is a listing from Ocaml utop:

```
# #require "core_extended";;
# open Core_extended.Std;;
# let cmd = "ls -al /";;
val cmd : bytes = "ls -al /"
# "ls -al /";;
- : bytes = "ls -al /"
# Shell.sh_one "ls -al /";;
- : bytes option =
Some
 "lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 sty 29 09:28 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic"
# Shell.sh_one cmd;;
Error: This expression has type bytes but an expression was expected of type
         ('a, unit, bytes, bytes option) Core.Std.format4 =
           ('a, unit, bytes, bytes, bytes, bytes option) format6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though they are syntactically identical, the `bytes` and `format` types are different.

That is handled by some dark magic inside the compiler which basically checks when it sees a string if it is bound to a format type.

In your case, the check is performed at the creation of `cmd`. At this point in the program, there is no way to know that it will be used as a format string. So it is given the type `bytes`. Later, you get to the usual "I don't do transtyping" from the obviously puzzled compiler.

```
let cmd : ('a,'b,'c,'d) Core.Std.format4 = "ls -al /";;
```

Here I just added a type information so that the compiler knows that "this is not a string, but a format string". Things should just work fine with that.

Comment: What if I have my command string stored in some variable? In this case I cannot use your solution, because it works only for literals. Is is possible to create `format4` from `bytes` variable? I know that `Scanf.format_from_string` creates `format6` but what about `format4`?

Comment: @trivelt `format6` and `format4` are compatible (the later is an alias on the former) so you should be fine using that function.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the type of `Core_extended.Shell.sh_one`, you will see the following

```
 val sh_one: ('a,unit,bytes,string option) format4 -> 'a
```

This means that the first argument of `sh_one` is a format string. For instance, one can use format specifier with `sh_one`:

```
Shell.sh_one "ls -%s /" "al"
```

Your issue stems from the fact that format string type,`format4`, and string or bytes are not the same type in OCaml.

Nevertheless, there is a bit of magic in the OCaml typechecker that makes it possible for strings and format strings to share the same literal syntax: if the typechecker notices that the expected type of string literal is in fact a format string, it reinterpret the string literal as a format string literal.

You can have a look a the phenomenon by yourself in utop by comparing

```
let s = "A simple string";;
```

> s : string = "A simple string"

and

```
 open CamlinternalFormatBasics 
(* ^ this help with making the format readable *)
 let fmt : _ format4 = "A format string"
```

> val fmt : ('a, 'b, 'c, 'a) format4 =
>     Format (String_literal ("A simple string", End_of_format), "A simple string")

An alternative to the explicit type annotation is to use the `format_of_string` function which marks a string literal as format string literal

```
 let fmt = format_of_string "A format string"
```

In brief, if you want to store a format string inside a variable you can either use an explicit type annotation or `format_of_string`